# Use a generic types value for a property expecting 'number | string | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This question uses React code but is specific to typescript rather than react.

I am using a simplified example to try and make this easier to read. I have a component `MyList` that takes one generic type argument that is passed to the props type.

This generic type infers an object to be used to generate a child component. I want to key each child component using a value of `T[keyof T]` || its index in `T[]`.

Creating the list and using the index is no problem but I can't figure out how to correctly type `listKey` so that it will work with reacts `key` property that is expecting `number | string | undefined`.

```
type MyListProps<T> = {
  list: T[],
  listKey: keyof T,
  contentKey: keyof T
}

class MyList<T extends object> extends React.Component<MyListProps<T>, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.list.map((value: T, index: number) => {
            const key = value[this.props.listKey];
            return (
              // Type T[keyof T] is not assignable 
              // to type 'number | string | undefined'
              <Item key={key}>{value[this.props.contentKey]}</Item>
            );
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How could I infer that the `listKey` type is assignable to the expected type of reacts `key` prop using a generic?

Comment: Honestly it doesn't matter so much as `key` is a semi magic property added by react that can be used on any component regardless of its definition. It is used to ensure react doesn't re-render components that haven't changed in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to assign the result of the index access to `key` you will need to restrict what that index operation can return. One way to do that is to use a constraint on `T`:

```
class MyList2<T extends Record<string, string | number >> extends React.Component<MyListProps2<T>, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.list.map((value: T, index: number) => {
            const key = value[this.props.listKey];
            return (
              <Item key={key}>{value[this.props.contentKey]}</Item>
            );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This does have the drawback of restricting the possible values you can have in `T` which might be a problem (or not depending on your use case).

Another more complicated option is to restrict just what indexing using `listKey` will return. This does require an extra type parameter, but it allows more flexibility:

```
type MyListProps<T, LK extends PropertyKey> = {
  list: Array<T & Record<LK, string>>,
  listKey: LK,
  contentKey: keyof T
}
declare const Item: React.FC<{}>

class MyList<T, LK extends PropertyKey> extends React.Component<MyListProps<T, LK>, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.list.map((value, index: number) => {
          const key = value[this.props.listKey];
          return (
            <Item key={key}>{value[this.props.contentKey]}</Item>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let x = <MyList listKey="a" contentKey="a" list={[
  { a: "", b: 0, p: {} }
]} ></MyList>
```

Or you could forgo type safety in this case and just use a type assertion.

Comment: extending the PropertyKey type looks like a really nice way to do this, I'll give that a shot, thanks for the answer.

Comment: After implementing it I realised what it was doing, and this is a beautiful solution, thank you very much!